# Tabs in Fragments - is this possible?

Tags: android

I use one Activity with Fragments and a Navigation Drawer. 
Depending on a click, I change the special Fragment.

Is it possible to use tabs in one of the Fragments? I need one Fragment with tabs under the Actionbar. Is this possible or is a solution to start a new Activity?

Comment: Yes, always the same error: the app is crashing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TabLayout` to do that.

fragment.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

fargment.class:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    //do what you want when tab 0 is selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //do what you want when tab 1 is selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //do what you want when tab 2 is selected
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```